# Can't make navbar colapse on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to close the Navbar on click.
 I've made it fullscreen using CSS but none of my JS attempts worked until now...

Tried adding to JS this line with no success :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--NAV BAR  -->
<div class="open-navbar-icon navbar-icon center">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="close-navbar-icon navbar-icon center">
      <div class="line line-1"></div>
      <div class="line line-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-list">
      <a id="target" class="nav-link center">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link center">Recomendações</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link center">Robot Infos</a>
      <a href="#bottom_link" class="nav-link center">Fale conosco</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding your CSS too.

Comment: How can I specify my css line inside JS?

Comment: You are trying to click on `.navbar-collapse.in` but it's not present on the HTML

Comment: There's no `.navbar-collapse`. `const nav = $('.navbar')[0]; $('.navbar-wrapper').click(function(){ nav.slideToggle(); });`